# Sequelize Transaction failing due to foreign key violation on parent table

Tags: transactions, sequelize.js, timeout, deadlock

I have 3 tables:

1. Company
2. OperationMaster
3. OperationCompanyXref

`OperationCompanyXref` is a child table for both `Company` and `OperationMaster`

Associations are:

```
OperationsCompanyXref.belongsTo(Company, { foreignKey: 'companyId' });
OperationsCompanyXref.belongsTo(Operations, { foreignKey: 'operationId' });
Company.hasMany(OperationsCompanyXref, { foreignKey: 'companyId' });
Operations.hasMany(OperationsCompanyXref, { foreignKey: 'operationId' });
```

OperationMaster already has 1 entry
When creating a new `Company` it should insert to 2 tables: `Company` and then `OperationsCompanyXref`

**Function to create a Company**

```
    async function createCompany(companyObject) {
      let transaction = await db.sequelizeConnection.transaction();
      try {
        var createCompany = await db.Company.create(companyObject, { transaction })
    
        for (let i = 0; i < companyObject.operations.length; i++) {
          await db.OperationCompanyXref.create({
            operationId: companyObject.operations[i],
            companyId: createCompany.id,
            status : true
          },transaction);
        }
        await transaction.commit();
        return { createCompany };
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        await transaction.rollback();
        return err;
      }
```

**Issue:**

*code: 'ER_LOCK_WAIT_TIMEOUT',
errno: 1205,
sqlState: 'HY000',
sqlMessage: 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction',
sql: 'INSERT INTO `OperationCompanyXrefs` (`id`,`status`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`,`companyId`,`operationId`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?);',*

I commented out the code to insert to OperationCompanyXrefs, and the API call was successful in inserting to Company. A manual insert to OperationCompanyXrefs also worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The `transaction` option should be passed inside `options` object:

```js
await db.OperationCompanyXref.create({
            operationId: companyObject.operations[i],
            companyId: createCompany.id,
            status : true
          },{ transaction });
```